# Google Sheet - Combine two tables dynamically including duplicates

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

In google sheets, I'm trying to expand something like a query or array that can:

- Join two tables together with a common identifier (in this case, fruit)
- Expand the results which can include multiple duplicates (if multiple people have the same type of fruit). Each owner-fruit combination will only occur once.
- Dynamically update the results over multiple rows/columns even if the source lists change
- Sort the results by one of the columns ("purchase date" from table 1 in this case)

[Here is an example google sheet (EDITABLE - feel free)](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12ppXfKA4ZF6XhNvhovLX50w8n2WMDdZh2nDuDbyckN0/edit#gid=0) where you can see the two source tables (Table 1 and 2), and the desired output table (done manually for now). Ccroll down in the sheet to play around with the formula-based output.

---

Here is a simple summary with an example:

- Table 1 includes a name, a fruit. A name may have multiple entries with different fruits (e.g. someone owns two types of fruit)
- Table 2 includes a fruit and potentially multiple rows of instructions for that fruit.
- Output table should include all of the instructions for each fruit alongside each person's name (so, a fruits set of instructions may show up multiple times depending on however many people own that fruit)

The idea is to have a set of "instructions" over multiple rows for each person-fruit.

This formula is able to get all the details for just a single fruit (without the person's name):

> =FILTER(query($E$3:$G$9, "select E,F,G"),$E$3:$E$9=""&$B$3&"")
>
> (where B3 = "Apple")

But I'm not sure if there's some way to join these together with the names and make it dynamic - so if more people or fruit are added, the output list is entirely updated.
E.g:

> ={person-fruit 1;person-fruit 2;person-fruit N}

I'd be completely fine using intermediary tables or other things to get the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a copy of the tab with a solution (Formulas highlighted in yellow). The approach is basically to stitch together text into a CSV type format. I separate the rows by ";", and the columns by ",". The last step is to use split/array formulas to parse it out.

Creating CSV type string:

```css
=arrayformula(
TEXTJOIN(",",true,
    Query(
           {arrayformula(";"&$A$3:$A$8&","&$C$3:$C$8),$B$3:$B$8},
           "Select Col1,'"&E3&","&F3&","&G3&"' where Col2 ='"&E3&"'")))
```

Parsing out String: (The exterior Query function is to clean it up / remove blank rows, and rearrange the columns to match)

```js
=query(
   arrayformula(split(
                       transpose(split(
                                  TEXTJOIN(";",true,J2:J10),
                                  ";",true,true)),",",true,true)),
    "Select Col1,Col3,Col2,Col4,Col5 where Col5 is not null",0)
```

The only limitation with this method would be that text join can only go up to 50k characters so if you are dealing with larger data sets, you have to repeat the second formula and stack it with { ; }.